# C++ threads cause issues on SDL2 rendering (since Ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, rendering, sdl-2

I noticed that my SDLD2/C++ application doesn't work properly or I changed nothing. So I tried to execute it on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM and it worked. After few tests, I noticed that if I take out my rendering function from the std::tread Tread function it reworks. But my program is now stucked when the "program" function is not finished.

Here is my code (in comment the previous thread implementation):

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>   
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>    
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include "const.hpp"
#include "maze_crea.hpp"
#include "maze_solver.hpp"

void program(SDL_Window* pWindow, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer){
    std::array<int, MAZE_SIZE<int>> maze;
    std::array<SDL_Rect, MAZE_SIZE<int>> squares;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAZE_SIZE<int>; i++){
        squares[i] = { (i % SIDE_SIZE<int>) * (WIDTHSCREEN<int> / SIDE_SIZE<int>), (i / SIDE_SIZE<int>) * (HEIGHTSCREEN<int> / SIDE_SIZE<int>), WIDTHSCREEN<int> / SIDE_SIZE<int>, HEIGHTSCREEN<int> / SIDE_SIZE<int> };
        if (((i % SIDE_SIZE<int>) % 2 == 0) || ((i / SIDE_SIZE<int>) % 2 == 0)){
            maze[i] = 0;
        } else {
            maze[i] = i;
        }
    }

    SDL_SetWindowTitle(pWindow, "Maze Solver (creation)");
    mazeCrea(pRenderer, maze, squares);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(pWindow, "Maze Solver (solution)");
    mazeSolver(pRenderer, maze, squares);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "[DEBUG] > %s", SDL_GetError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    SDL_Window* pWindow{ nullptr };
    SDL_Renderer* pRenderer{ nullptr };

     if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WIDTHSCREEN<unsigned int>, HEIGHTSCREEN<unsigned int>, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN, &pWindow, &pRenderer) < 0)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "[DEBUG] > %s", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    //std::thread Thread(program, pWindow, pRenderer);
    program(pWindow, pRenderer);

    SDL_Event events;

     while (true)
    {
         while (SDL_PollEvent(&events))
        {
            switch (events.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
                SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
                SDL_Quit();
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Thread.join();

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How properly handle the case my "program" fucntion needs time but I want to be able to quit the app at any time so my event loop needs to be also accessible.

Comment: [Why are you trying to call SDL_Renderer functions from a different thread?](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.5/include/SDL_render.h#L44-L45)

Comment: @genpfault Because if I let my "program" function (which calls the rendering functions) out a thread I can't stop it from the window cross for example until the end and my OS throws a "doesn't respond" message. For sure it isn't the right way to do that but I'm learning and I ask to know how properly handle the render and the window logic.

Comment: If you wish to still use events while doing other things you need to include those things in your game loop which includes generating the maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the generation and solving code from the rendering.
The simplest you can do is simply to cut the program in half, with a single shared variables between them to communicate the state.

In this case, the state is really just `maze`.

In your main loop, generate `squares` in advance. Then for every iteration of your game loop read the state from `maze` and update `squares` to match.
In the thread, solve the maze and write the results back to `maze` or a secondary shared datastructure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. That is a real and interesting answer